# Non-factors MVC Grid sort and filter inoperable

Tags: nonfactors-mvc-grid

I'm running v7.2 of the NonFactors mvc grid and have noticed that clicking either the sort button or the filter button results in nothing happening.  There are no JS errors either.

Diving further into the event listeners on these button I see that nothing in the mvc-grid.js file is bound to them (whereas they are in a working grid).

Is there a step I've missed in activating the grids client side?  Perhaps a JS call needs to be made?  I've not seen any such thing in the documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Funny how you can search for days and find no answer and the minute you post a question on here you find the answer immediately.

If this happens to you, put this script somewhere that runs on every page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelectorAll(".mvc-grid").forEach(element => new MvcGrid(element));
</script>
```